# SharePoint 2019 - People Search is not displaying user profile picture in search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

We are facing an issue to display user profile picture in people search. It's displaying default photo of person.

Let me give overview of current environment setup.

We have configured the SharePoint 2019 with 3 tiers SharePoint farm.

We have configured 2 applications with host header as below:

1. Intranet site
2. My site

We have configured following services,

1. User profile service with AD direct import sync and setup my site.
2. Configured Search service with content source crawl URLs as below:
3. sps3s://mysiteurl
4. https://intranetsite

We have checked following possibility to overcome an issue but didn't worked anything:

1. Verified the metadata property and crawl property mapping for ows_picture, Picture URL
2. Search crawl should not be displayed any errors for my site
3. Crawl and search service accounts should have proper permission on user profile service, search service application and on web application level
4. CrossDomainPhotosEnabled = true
5. User information list (hidden list) is displaying proper profile picture.
6. Checked proper permission assigned on profile_db in database
7. I have observed that people search result is displaying below similar user profile picture URL - /search/15/_layouts/userphoto.aspx?size=M&URL=https://mysite/user profile/profile picture/abc_mlength.jpg

When I have tried to access the direct my site Url the it's prompting credentials and after enter the correct credentials it's display proper image. So, user profile sync is working properly.

I think an issue with userphoto.aspx (i.e. proxy) page to retrieve photo from mysite host site collection and display in people search but couldn't found any solution how to resolve this.

I highly appreciate your suggestion or any assistance if I have missed anything on above points.

Note:- I did the same configuration in other environment and it's working fine.

Looking forward your suggestion or any assistance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're using ADI which does not support picture import, are users uploading their pictures to their profile?

Comment: Yes, we have upgraded the mysite  from SharePoint 2013 to 2016 to 2019 which contains user's uploaded photos.

Comment: Additional note: I have checked with hardcoded intranet site URL of other environment where the user profile picture is properly displayed in people search with mysite of current environment and it's worked fine for me so, I think an issue with userphoto.aspx page in current environment. E.g. https://intranetsiteofotherenvironment/_layouts/15/userphotos.apsx?size=M&url=https://mysiteofcurrentenvironment/user photos/profile picture/abc_mlength.jpg.  Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 0):

An issue has been after restart the server and sometime profile picture may take long time to reflect on site